# How to hide and show the div by selecting option in select form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have created a select option with displaying 10 values from count of 0 to 10. On changing the options I made a function that display targeted form div. But after unexpectedly clicking upon wrong option I am selecting option again but this time the both div's of both values are displaying instead of clicked on last one how can I avoid this by just showing the last clicked value div.

---

```
//select code
 <select class="form-control" name="subjectcount" onchange="showDiv(this)">
                        <option id= 'zero' value="0">Select Subject</option>
                        <option id= 'one' value="1">1</option>
                        <option id= 'two' value="2">2</option>
                        <option id= 'three' value="3">3</option>
                        <option id= 'four' value="4">4</option>
                        <option id= 'five' value="5">5</option>
                        <option id= 'six' value="6">6</option>
                        <option id= 'seven' value="7">7</option>
                        <option id= 'eight' value="8">8</option>
                        <option id= 'nine' value="9">9</option>
                        <option id= 'zero' value="10">10</option>
                    </select>


----------
default hidden div's
 <div id='onesub' style="display:none">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject1</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'acsubject1','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'HOD','placeholder'=>'Subject1 Name']);?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>

                <div id='twosub' style="display:none">
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject1</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'acsubject1','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'HOD','placeholder'=>'Subject1 Name']);?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                   <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject1</label>
                     <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'acsubject2','class'=>'form-control','id'=>'HOD','placeholder'=>'Subject1 Name']);?>
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>


----------
javascript code
<script>
  function showDiv(elem){
   if(elem.value == 1)
      document.getElementById('onesub').style.display = "block";
else if(elem.value == 2)
      document.getElementById('twosub').style.display = "block";
}
</script>
```

Comment: hide all div first then show only what is needed to be shown

Comment: will u suggest how to implement . because i tried to hide first and display later according to the value but it didn't worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `document.querySelectorAll` to set `style.display=none` to all div's on change of the `select`:

```js
function showDiv(elem){
  document.querySelectorAll('#onesub,#twosub').forEach(function(d){
    d.style.display = "none";
  });
  if(elem.value == 1){
    document.getElementById('onesub').style.display = "block";
  }
  else if(elem.value == 2){
    document.getElementById('twosub').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="subjectcount" onchange="showDiv(this)">
  <option id= 'zero' value="0">Select Subject</option>
  <option id= 'one' value="1">1</option>
  <option id= 'two' value="2">2</option>
  <option id= 'three' value="3">3</option>
  <option id= 'four' value="4">4</option>
  <option id= 'five' value="5">5</option>
  <option id= 'six' value="6">6</option>
  <option id= 'seven' value="7">7</option>
  <option id= 'eight' value="8">8</option>
  <option id= 'nine' value="9">9</option>
  <option id= 'zero' value="10">10</option>
</select>


<div id='onesub' style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject1</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='twosub' style="display:none">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject1</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject1</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply hide all the divs before showing the last clicked div.

```
    <script>
      function showDiv(elem){
       [].forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.alldiv'), function (el) {
  el.style.display = 'none';
});

       if(elem.value == 1)
          document.getElementById('onesub').style.display = "block";
    else if(elem.value == 2)
          document.getElementById('twosub').style.display = "block";
    }
    </script>
```

Give class `alldiv` to each divs.

Comment: Did you give class to all divs?

Answer (score 0):

Set `style.display = "none"` based on condition like this.

```js
function showDiv(elem) {
  if (elem.value == 1) {
    document.getElementById('onesub').style.display =
      "block";
    document.getElementById('twosub').style.display = "none";
  } else if (elem.value == 2) {
    document.getElementById('onesub').style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById('twosub').style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<select onchange="showDiv(this)">
 <option value="0">Select</option>
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<div id='onesub' style="display:none">1</div>
<div id='twosub' style="display:none">2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of multiple conditions u can directly show selected element through this code.

```js
function showDiv(elem){
 var ch = [];
 ch = document.getElementsByClassName('allsub');
 for(var i=0;i<ch.length;i++){
  ch[i].style.display = "none";
 }
 
  var id = (elem[elem.selectedIndex].id);
  document.getElementById(id+'sub').style.display = "block";
  
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" name="subjectcount" onchange="showDiv(this)">
  <option id= 'zero' value="0">Select Subject</option>
  <option id= 'one' value="1">1</option>
  <option id= 'two' value="2">2</option>
  <option id= 'three' value="3">3</option>
  <option id= 'four' value="4">4</option>
</select>


<div id='onesub' style="display:none" class="allsub">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject 1</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id='twosub' style="display:none" class="allsub">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject 2</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">2
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id='threesub' style="display:none" class="allsub">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject 3</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">3
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

   <div id='foursub' style="display:none" class="allsub">
  <div class="form-group">
     <label for="subject1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject 4</label>
       <div class="col-sm-10">4
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```